# Error with subfig "subfloat has an extra }" Please help

Tags: subfig

[image]this is my code it ran on a different machine at work just fine but when I opened it on my personal computer at home it would not compile. it keeps telling me that there is a additional } but when I remove it it says I forgot a }. I am out of ideas any help is greatly appreciated.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Cells Treated with Same Drug Input During PI and PII]{{includegraphics[width=6cm]{AtoA.png}}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Average Punctae per Cell]{{\includegraphics[width=9cm, height = 8cm]{AnalysisPIPII_01.png} }}%
    \caption{\textbf{(a)} side-by-side images taken for PI (left) and PII (right) for VC, RAP, and BAF. VC-R and VC-B represent vehicle control images taken with a Fluorescent Olympus IX83-Inverted Microscope with specific light intensity settings for Rapamycin and Bafilomycin respectively. \textbf{(b)} Average punctae per cell analysis using SparQ pluggin for FIJI(ImageJ). Error bars represent standard deviation ($\pm$SD). }%
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a \ in front of the first includegraphics command.

Comment: I just added the "\" but did not fix the problem